# Using ExcelServices in Office 365?

Tags: excel, office365

I use Office 365 plan E3 and I want to copy and modify an excel file within a document library on the server. Goal is to read some values from a listitem and update the excel with these values. In the excel file there are several formulas that do the reporting the customer wants.

I already tried developing a sandboxed solution with excelservices.dll referenced, but SharePoint doesn't allow to execute this solution because of partial trust problems.

I also tried to generate a proxy for ExcelServices.asmx, but WCF needs a configuration file and in O365 I can't change web.config to add the config-sections - and it's not so much fun to generate and parse soap messages manually.

Are there any suggestions how to solve this or is it still impossible?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint have some embedded function of Excel services - maybe You can use webpart like Excel lists or something similar?